# Filename Formula changes to name of second workbook that is opened up. What formula can I use so this wont happen again?

Tags: excel-formula

here is the formula that changes when I open another workbook. it takes that new workbook that I opened up and places the data into the already open workbook:

1. I expect the workbook that contains this to only show that workbooks name.
2. I want to have multiple files open that have this same formula to detect their name. (or any formula for that matter).
3. I want to use this file name in VBA eventually.

> =MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))+1, SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))-1)

Can someone help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the right answer to this, i know it will help someone. I didnt intend to answer my own question.

In the formula you have to reference something in that workbook so it only derives the data from that specific workbook. that was the trick.

Formula:

```
=LEFT(MID(CELL("filename",C41),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",C41))+1, SEARCH("]",CELL("filename",C41))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename",C41))-1),75)
```

VBA Equivalent:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("C43").Formula2R1C1 = _
    "=MID(CELL(""filename""),SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))+1, SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename""))-SEARCH(""["",CELL(""filename""))-1)"
```